# Why is the skeleton from SkeletonFrame empty (Kinect)?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

So I wrote this eventhandler which I call out on `SkeletonFrameReady`.

```
sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += InitializeHandler;
sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
```

The idea is that it initializes the sensor in a way that it calculates the averages of the joints' coordinates. However the `initSkeleton` remains `null` so no vectors are added. Why is this happening?

```
private void InitializeHandler(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (frame <= 10)
            {
                frame += 1;
                using (SkeletonFrame initSkeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
                {
                    if (this.initSkeletons == null)
                    {
                        this.initSkeletons = new Skeleton[initSkeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    }
                    initSkeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(initSkeletons);
                    Skeleton initSkeleton = this.initSkeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (initSkeleton != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Joint j in initSkeleton.Joints)
                        {
                            Vector3D tmp = new Vector3D(j.Position.X, j.Position.Y, j.Position.Z);
                            vectors.Add(tmp);
                            Console.Write(vectors.Count);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        // ... calculations
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You analyse only the first 10 frames. When no sekeleton is found in the first 10 Frames (in less than a second), your application will not do anything.

Execute the instruction `frame += 1` only when a skeleton is found.

```
if (initSkeleton != null)
{
     frame += 1;
     foreach (Joint j in initSkeleton.Joints) {...}    
}
```